# Scala - ScalaTest: simulate input while testing

Tags: scala, scalatest

I've a application that's run on top of terminal.

This App uses only Scala and SBT and I'm testing it using ScalaTest.

I want to test all components like a integration test, running the app, but, for that, I want to simulate the user sending values via standard input using something like a robot. Most important of all, when I call `readLine` or `readInt`, I want to send differents values while testing.

Thanks in advance!

---

## Edit 1

So, I've this code. It basically prints the options for the user. I want, for example, to send `1`, and then `3,4`, to create a new Cell and check my CellArray to check if a new cell was really created in that position.

```
do {
  println("Select one of the options: \n \n"); 
  println("[1] Make a cell alive");
  println("[2] Next generation");
  println("[3] Halt");

  print("\n \n Option: ");

  option = parseOption(readLine)

}while(option == 0)

option match {
  case MAKE_CELL_ALIVE => makeCellAlive
  case NEXT_GENERATION => nextGeneration
  case HALT => halt
}
```

Comment: Basically, what you'll be wanting to do is have a test implementation of the edges of your program (readLine/readInt) that provide either hand coded or generated (eg. ScalaCheck) values. Drop some of your code in here and we can try to help with more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach will be something along these lines.

```
// This is the class containing the logic you want to test
class MyInputThing {
  def readInput() = readLine

  def thingIWantToTest = {
    val input = readInput
    doStuffWithInput(input)
  }
}

// This test class returns a value representing something you want to verify.
class TestMyInputThing extends MyInputThing {
  override def readInput = "123"
}
```

Then, in your test, use TestMyInputThing.thingIWantToTest() and validate the response. You can also pull out readInput into a trait, parameterise the creation of TestMyInputThing, etc, in order to clean this up. I would also recommend looking into ScalaCheck so you don't need to handcode test scenarios.